# Converting a NEMA 6-50p plug to NEMA 10-30p

Tags: wiring, electrical, plug

I received a compressor recently that has a (I think) 6-50p plug on it but my dryer is currently plugged into a 10-30r receptacle and that's the only 240v I have available.  I'm renting the house so I would prefer not making changes to the receptacle.

Without thinking much of it, I purchased a 10-30p plug to put on the compressor, but while I was about to install it I realized the wiring is different between the two.  I know very little about this stuff and I thought I should seek advice before doing anything stupid.

If I'm not mistaken, the 6-50p is grounded while the 10-30p is not.

What would be involved in replacing the 6-50p plug with a 10-30p plug?  Is this even possible?

Here are some pics.  Thanks!

**The current plug on compressor:**

[image: current compressor plug] [image: current plug]

**The one I purchased (that fits my the receptacle in my garage):**

[image]

**Compressor info:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: honestly they both look grounded

Comment: @C_Elegans the paper that came with it says "This device is not for grounding use. Connect to non-grounding circuits only, unless it is to be used for a range or clothes dryer in accordance with NEC 250-140 (1999 NEC)" whatever that means :)

Comment: Also I think there's a neutral wire instead of a ground wire (for the middle prong)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is exactly applicable, but here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116738/dryer-outlet-4-prong-to-3-prong they imply that the dryer plug you have could have neutral on the L shaped lug instead of ground.  Other's in the discussion disagree with this.

Comment: NEMA 10-30 plugs are non grounding (hot-neutral-hot). It will not burst into flames if you connect it, but in the event of a fault the compressor chassis could become live.

Comment: @τεκ thanks my only other optino would be to run a newer receptacle from the breaker box right?  Can I ground the compressor itself, in case of a fault?  Is that even a thing (seriously I have no idea what I'm doing lol)? And lastly, if/when I do decide to just wire it up, would it be the same way it is now (white/black on left/right and then green middle)?  Thank you!

Comment: If you have an ohmmeter, you can unplug the dryer and measure from the L shaped lug to a bare metal point on the dryer.  If they  are connected (~1 ohm or so), then the dryer is wired as if the L lug is ground.  That does not necessarily mean that the outlet is wired that way, but the compressor would then be at least wired the same as the dryer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is where you source your ground. I updated the picture to show it better. The easy fix is if your wall has the ground wire but not connected. New dryer connections have 4 prongs to ensure you have ground protection as well as neutral.

Your current wall has only neutral on the 3rd prong. Neutral is meant to carry current and such if you touch it there is a potential hazard in case of a failure. Your compressor has ground PE on the 3rd prong, therefore connecting to the wall by just replacing the connector to match the wall would technically work, but it might not be safe.

The correct approach is to rewire your wall, by adding the ground PE which is probably just in there but not connected (bare copper wire). And then replace the compressor connector with one that connects only the two hot lines and the ground wire, as the compressor does not use the neutral.

[image]

Comment: Hi isn't the 15 FLA the amperage?  The blurry picture makes that look like AMP but I think the 40 is MAX AMB (not sure what that is).  Going to post a replacement photo for that...

Comment: Replaced photo with a better one

Comment: Where does the rating plate say that the compressor requires 40A?  It says MAX AMB (ambient temperature) is 40 C.  It says 15.0 FLA (Full Load Amps).

Comment: THe new picture is much better, I had read MAX AMP rather than AMB. The C should have called my attention. The change should be pretty straight forward then,the ground of the current connection will work perfectly for the grounding needs of the chassis.

Comment: yeah, ground is important. it says so on the label "Failure to connect...."

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm confused about what you're saying. 1. Are you saying it will have ground on the third prong? Why would it have ground if it's an nongrounding plug?  2. I'm not sure what your diagram is meant to illustrate.  There's three wires on the compressor cable: black, white, and green (ground).  Can I put the black and white on the left and right, and put the green (ground) in the middle of the 10-30P even though 10-30p uses neutral instead of ground for the middle prong?

Comment: updated answer to be more clear. 1. you need ground on 3rd prong. 2. Wall has 3 wire but one of them is neutral. Compressor has 3 wires but one of them is ground. You need a ground source. My advise is you rewire your wall to have neutral and ground an 14-30 is pretty common.